How to prevent SwiftUI TextField from doing "smart editing"
If you create a SwiftUI TextField, it does some "smart editing" that you may or may not want in your application.
Examples:

If you quickly type  "a  " (a letter followed by 2 spaces) it assumes you are ending a sentence, and converts your text to that letter followed by a period. (I believe there is a user setting to turn that off.)
If you type "..." (3 periods) it converts it to an ellipsis character (…) which is a single unicode glyph.
If you enter text enclosed in single or double straight quotes (" or ') it converts them to open and closing quotes.

It also does autocorrection and auto-capitalization by default. You can turn those off with the .disableAutocorrection(true) and .autocapitalization(.none) ViewModifiers, respectively.
How do you turn off the other "smart editing" features if you don't want them, as a developer? (Not as an iOS user. I want to flag one or more TextFields in my app so that they do not provide these editing features.)

It seems that you can use the viewModifier  .keyboardType(.asciiCapable).
Since all the above characters are non-ASII, it has the effect of preventing those replacements.
